# Problem converting an Array<T> to Observable<Array<T>> using RxJava2

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

Basically what I am trying is to return an `Observable<Array<T>>`. I double-checked that `getAllCategoriesFromDB()` returns `Array<Categroies>`. `categoryDao` is a kotlin class.

I tried using this code:

```
fun getAllCategoriesFromDB(): Observable<Array<Categories>>
    {
        return categoryDao.selectAllCategories().toObservable()
    }
```

However the returned type is `Observable<Categories>` instead of `Observable<Array<Categories>>`

I followed the example from [here](https://medium.com/corebuild-software/android-repository-pattern-using-rx-room-bac6c65d7385) (scroll down to the repository example code)

My `selectAllCategories()` looks like this (keep in mind I'm using Room):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Categories")
    fun selectAllCategories(): Array<Categories>
```

Help or advice would be much appreciated since it's the first time I'm working with RxJava2.

Comment: post your selectAllCategories method

Comment: @VladimirBerezkin I added it but I don't think it will be of much help

Comment: Does `Observable.fromIterable()` not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this code. It might not look as clean or be the best solution but at least it works:

```
var categories = categoryDao.selectAllCategories()
var observable = Observable.fromArray(categories)
```